# What is the difference between a python itterator and a python generator?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I am looking to understand what purpose a generator serves.

For example, in the following

what is the practical difference between

```
iter([x for x in range(1,10)])
```

and

```
(x for x in range(1,10))
```

?

why should I use a generator at all?

Comment: `[x for x in range(1,10)]` is going to create the real list. If you have 1 billion elements, it will use several gigabytes. Not the case with the generator expression (which is also useless, just use `range(1,10)`

Comment: `iter` provides interfaces for `next()` method, useful to iterate manually on your list.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, your answer is appreciated, but I am aware of what would happen if the list had a billion elements. I am looking to find out whether the specific two pieces of code above have any distinction. I chose a short list deliberately. This is an attempt to get at the presence or lack of a conceptual distinction within the language construct. The code is a toy problem in which to contemplate that.

Comment: I have closed as duplicate as the duplicate explains everything I wanted to post as an answer and more. You can refine your question/post another one if something isn't clear.

Comment: in general it's better to use builtins vs generator comprehensions because the loop is done in a compiled language for the first one so it may be faster. it's also shorter.